# EmberJS body.ember-application CSS override

Tags: css, ember.js, margin

It seems impossible to override the CSS of the `<body>` tag of an EmberJS application.
It inherits the `ember-application` class, and this has many of the browsers default values, including a margin of 8px.

I want to get rid of this margin around `<body>`, but none of these two methods worked:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

body.ember-application {
    margin: 0;
}
```

`!important` does not help either.

Any idea of what I could do? Removing the body tag itself do not work, as Ember will add one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ember-application class has no css associated with it and just putting in

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

is enough to handle it.  It's likely you have another CSS element winning the CSS war, or you have an inside element pushing the padding making it appear so.

Example of margin 0 working: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vaquhuwo/1/edit

Comment: Although adding it to my CSS did not help, your JSbin gave me a good answer: adding normalize made it work. I have no idea why.